# Jquery: Mudar janela em foco no navegador ao clicar em link

Tags: jquery, navegador-de-internet

Olá,
Gostaria de saber se tem como fazer o seguinte:
Ao clicar num link de um site, caso eu ja tenha ele aberto, essa aba se torna o foco, caso não, abre uma nova aba normalmente.
Obrigada!

Comment: Só é possível se clicando no link for abrir uma janela pop. Se a janela não foi criada clicando no link ela é criada. Se perder o foco e clicar no link novamente a pop recebe o foco.

Comment: Obrigada, irei verificar essa solução.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso já foi possível no passado, em situações bem específicas. Mas por motivos de segurança, os navegadores hoje impedem isso.

Se você pudesse mudar o foco para outra aba, você provavelmente teria controle total sobre ela. Isso seria o pesadelo de quem tivesse que garantir a segurança de um site de lojas online ou de Internet banking.

Você pode procurar por soluções para isso no Stack Overflow em inglês, mas garanto de antemão que:

- Você não vai encontrar uma resposta que funcione em todos os navegadores;
- Provavelmente o que você encontrar já estará obsoleto e não funcionará mais.

Se você tem a necessidade de mudar drasticamente o que usuário deve visualizar em um dado momento, então provavelmente mudar a aba que o usuário acessa não vai atender a sua necessidade. É melhor pensar em outras formas de apresentação para a sua aplicação.

Comment: Obrigada pela resposta.